# vlookup with a condiition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, dataframe, vlookup

I'm doing an analysis of basketball teams.  I've been using pandas but recently got stuck on how to do the equivalent of an Excel VLookup, with a condition.  I have all team data (there are 30 teams) since 1985 (all the way up to 2013).  I added a column called Year3, which adds three years onto the Year column.  I want to do a vlookup in a new column (which we'll call Perc3) that takes the Year and returns the percentile.  The condition that makes this confusing for me is it has to be matching the year AND team.

`Team           Year     Percentile  WLPer LgRnk W   L  Year3
   308  Atlanta Hawks   1997    0.793103    0.683   23  56  26  2000
    23  Atlanta Hawks   1986    0.782609    0.610   18  50  32  1989
    69  Atlanta Hawks   1988    0.695652    0.610   16  50  32  1991
   337  Atlanta Hawks   1998    0.689655    0.610   20  50  32  2001
   252  Atlanta Hawks   1995    0.518519    0.512   14  42  40  1998
   395  Atlanta Hawks   2000    0.172414    0.341   5   28  54  2003`

so for the first row (labeled 308) the Year3 is 2000.  For the column I want to create (Perc3), I want the corresponding percentile for (Team: Atlanta Hawks) and (Year:2000).    Is there any easy way to do this?

Expected output:

`Team           Year     Percentile  WLPer LgRnk W   L  Year3  Perc3
   308  Atlanta Hawks   1997    0.793103    0.683   23  56  26  2000  0.172414
    23  Atlanta Hawks   1986    0.782609    0.610   18  50  32  1989  0.840000
    69  Atlanta Hawks   1988    0.695652    0.610   16  50  32  1991  0.555556
   337  Atlanta Hawks   1998    0.689655    0.610   20  50  32  2001  0.172414
   252  Atlanta Hawks   1995    0.518519    0.512   14  42  40  1998  0.689655
   395  Atlanta Hawks   2000    0.172414    0.341   5   28  54  2003  0.275862`

Comment: So your DataFrame has a row for the Hawks with Year=2000 right? It'd be helpful it you posted a fuller DataFrame, and your expected output.

Comment: thanks - yes there is a row for Hawks with year = 2000.  Essentially, I have all years 1985-2013 for all teams. the fact there are two conditions for the vlookup (year and team) confuses me.  I added the expected output.  if u look for row 308 and row 395, it should show the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work if there are no gaps (i.e., within a team no years are skipped) in the panel.

First, sort by ['team','year'] so your panel looks like the following:

```
df = df.sort(['team','year'])
print df

   team  year  ptile
0     A  2000   0.40
1     A  2001   0.42
2     A  2002   0.46
3     A  2003   0.30
4     A  2004   0.38
5     A  2005   0.40
6     A  2006   0.35
7     A  2007   0.50
8     B  2000   0.60
9     B  2001   0.70
10    B  2002   0.55
11    B  2003   0.65
12    B  2004   0.75
13    B  2005   0.72
14    B  2006   0.66
15    B  2007   0.56
```

Second, use the `shift` and `where` commands to create the percentile3 column:

```
same_team = df.team == df.team.shift(-3)
df['ptile3'] = df['ptile'].shift(-3).where(same_team)
print df

   team  year  ptile  ptile3
0     A  2000   0.40    0.30
1     A  2001   0.42    0.38
2     A  2002   0.46    0.40
3     A  2003   0.30    0.35
4     A  2004   0.38    0.50
5     A  2005   0.40     NaN
6     A  2006   0.35     NaN
7     A  2007   0.50     NaN
8     B  2000   0.60    0.65
9     B  2001   0.70    0.75
10    B  2002   0.55    0.72
11    B  2003   0.65    0.66
12    B  2004   0.75    0.56
13    B  2005   0.72     NaN
14    B  2006   0.66     NaN
15    B  2007   0.56     NaN
```

You could also use `shift` to accomplish this within a `groupby`/`apply`:

```
df['ptile3'] = df.groupby('team')['ptile'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-3))
```

Comment: this is pretty awesome, never thought about shift.  I did try to use groupby and apply with a vlookup and couldn't quite crack it.  this works perfectly, but just for my own educational use, if there were some years skipped and a vlookup was needed, would you know what to do?

Comment: I think the easiest would be to use the `resample` command to add the skipped years (your percentile variable would be missing in those years), and then you could just use `shift` and `where` in exactly the same way.